# When does InnoDB acquire gap locks on the post gap of the selected/updated records?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, deadlock, blocking

I am currently learning about `Gap Lock` in the InnoDB engine, In MySQL [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#:%7E:text=A%20gap%20lock%20is%20a,of%2015%20into%20column%20t.) they say,
InnoDB will acquire a gap locks **only** on the preceding gap, but on this [Percona article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/) as I understood from their example, InnoDB will acquire gap locks on the pre **and** post gaps!

I tried to do my tests

```
CREATE TABLE T ( INT ID PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO T 
VALUES (1), (2), (4), (7), (9);

//session-1
BEGIN;

//session-2
BEGIN;

//session-1
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ID BETWEEN 4 and 7 FOR UPDATE;

//session-2 
INSERT INTO T VALUES(3);
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

INSERT INTO T VALUES(8);
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

//session-1 
commit;

//session-2
INSERT INTO T VALUES(8);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

commit;
```

So the result is the same as the result described in [Percona article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/)!
Is MySQL doc wrong or i just missed something? I really can't understand.

P.S: the Isolation-level for both sessions is the default one "REPATABLE READ".

Comment: "they say, InnoDB will acquire a gap locks **only** on the preceding gap". Not sure where you see that. On the linked page I read: "a lock on a gap between index records, or a lock on the gap before the first or after the last index record".

Comment: Maybe it is finding the row after "7" and locking the gap before that?  Please provide `SHOW ENGINE=INNODB STATUS;`